# Avoiding inserting subarrays duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am stumped at the moment. Essentially I am trying to create a function where it takes a number as a reference and an array, and find a combination (the reference number and two from the array) that equals to zero WITHOUT having any duplicates combination in `subArray`.

```
function helper(number, arr){
  console.log(arr, 'this is arr')
  let answer = [];
  let subArray = []
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    for(let y = i + 1; y < arr.length; y++){
      var newCombo = [arr[i], arr[y]]
      subArray.push(newCombo) <-- avoid duplicates here
    }
  }
  subArray.forEach( combo =>{
    var referenceAndArray = [number].concat(combo)
    //result will check it adds up to zero
    var result = referenceAndArray.reduce( (accum, value) =>{
      return accum += value;
    },0)

    if(result === 0){ 
      answer.push(referenceAndArray)
    }
  })

  return answer
}

helper(-1, [-1,-1,0,1,2] --> [ [-1, 0, 1 ], [-1, -1, 2] ]
```

We can assume that the array are sorted from the start

I tried testing using `Array.includes` but it seems that it doesn't work well with having subArrays.

Comment: find just 1 combination or all possible combinations?

Comment: find all possible combinations without any duplicates

Comment: Arrays are compared by identity not by value, so `[] !== []`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since array are compared by identity and not value, you could join the array content and compare that to see if it already exists.

Basically replace `subArray.push(newCombo) <-- avoid duplicates here`

with

`let exists = subArray.some(combo => combo.join() === newCombo.join());
      if (!exists) {
        subArray.push(newCombo); 
      }`

For example if you have an array containing `[[-1, -1, 2], [-1, 0, 1]]` and when you find another combination `[-1, -1, 2]`; before inserting it we check if it already exists, and add it only if not. To do this would loop through the array checking if string "-1,-1,2" already exists using `.some()` (true as long as 1 element in the array matches). In this case we compare against "-1,-1,2" and "-1,0,1" so `exists` is true, hence we skip adding it into the array.

Comment: Worked great! I wasn't aware of `Array.prototype.some`. Def useful!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Set`, and store the string versions of the pairs, which will guarantee no duplicates are stored. This will work faster than looking up the element in an array

Here is your code with minimal adaptation to make it work that way:

```js
function helper(number, arr){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(arr), 'this is arr');
  let answer = [];
  let subArray = [];
  let uniques = new Set;
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    for(let y = i + 1; y < arr.length; y++){
      uniques.add(arr[i] + ',' + arr[y]); // add primitive (string) to set.
    }
  }
  uniques.forEach( s => {
    // now get the number parts of the stored string:
    var referenceAndArray = [number].concat(s.split(',').map(Number));
    //result will check it adds up to zero
    var result = referenceAndArray.reduce( (accum, value) =>{
      return accum += value;
    }, 0)

    if(result === 0){ 
      answer.push(referenceAndArray);
    }
  })

  return answer;
}

var result = helper(-1, [-1,-1,0,1,2]); //--> [ [-1, 0, 1 ], [-1, -1, 2] ]
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```